# First fundamental form (Surface)

Tags: differential-geometry

Specify which of the followingn can play the role of the first fundamental form for a surface: $$ds^2=du^2+4dudv+dv^2  \\  ds^2=du^2+4dudv+4dv^2\\ ds^2=du^2-4dudv+6dv^2 \\ ds^2=du^2+4dudv-2dv^2$$ I think the first one is the answer. I dont know how can I justify it (If it is correct).

Comment: I think you must have $EG-F^2 >0$, don't know if its sufficient though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing that was overlooked is the what the coefficients actually are with respect to a parametrization $\sigma(u,v)$.

$$E = \|\sigma_u\|^2, F = \sigma_u \cdot \sigma_v, G = \|\sigma_v\|^2$$

i.e the first and last coefficients are non-negative. The rules out the last one. I think you should be able to rule out the others by using the fact that,

$$ a \cdot b = \|a\| \|b\| \cos \theta$$

For instance, in the third equation you have $-4=\sigma_u \cdot \sigma_v = \sqrt{6} \cos \theta$. Can you solve that equation for a real-value $\theta$? The comment @Rene makes is sufficient since we can use it since the first fundamental form determines an area form (locally) on our surface.

$$\iint_U \|\sigma_u \times \sigma_v\| \ du dv = \iint_{U} \sqrt{EG - F^2} \ du \ dv$$

$\textbf{Edit}$: I apologize, I forgot about the factor $2$ in the middle coefficient. And so we should have $\sigma_u \cdot \sigma_v = \frac{1}{2} K$ where $K$ is the middle coefficient presented in the forms you gave.

Comment: the equation $-4=\sqrt{6}\cos \theta$ does not have real root. I do not understand how will I compute this integral?

Comment: As the equation cannot be solved for real value of theta then this rules out 3rd equation. But the problem is, If i write a similar equation for 1st and 2nd equations then they will also be ruled out.... So what kind of reasoning do I have to make here?

Comment: Or does this mean that none of the above equation can play role of the first fundamental form of surface?

Comment: Yes, it would seem as though none of them work.

Comment: No, $F=-2$, not $-4$.

Comment: The first fundamental form is $E du^2+ 2F dudv + G dv^2$. Why?

Comment: I know, I know. I just remembered that. I forgot about the $2$.

Comment: To answer the question why? You are just taking a vector in the tangent space at a point on your surface which has basis $\sigma_u, \sigma_v$. Then you dot it with itself and you get the first fundamental form.

Comment: In basic terms, it's FOIL. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: I know. I'm sorry. I made an edit. Thank you for catching that, it was so forgetful of me.

Comment: Sure. But don't use the letter $K$ ... which stands for Gaussian curvature :) Just write the formula for the first fundamental form as I did, with the $2$ in there. :) ... Also, by the way, the OP never stated whether this is an abstract Riemannian surface or a surface sitting in $\Bbb R^3$. It's not obvious that a given (positive definite) first fundamental form can be (locally) produced by an embedding in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Okay, I won't use $K$. I assumed we were in this context based on the tag. If we are in the context you mention, I might as well delete this because I don't know that subject yet. It seems as though we were on the same page based on his comments.

Comment: I honestly don't know what the OP was expected to know/do, other than check for positive definiteness, as you suggested. Your dot product thing is nothing more or less than that.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood If $F=-2$ then $-2=\sqrt{6} \cos \theta$ has real root. So can this serve as a first dundamental form?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood If I write similar equations for first and second equations then we get: $2=\cos \theta$ does not have real root but $2=\sqrt4 \cos \theta$ has real root. So can both 2nd and third equations serve as first fundamental form or do I have to make further reasoning to select one out of them?

Comment: As @TedShifrin pointed out, the problem as stated, has holes in it. Let us assume the statement means, suppose you are given a surface $S$ and you compute its fundamental form, then which of the following is a possible result. Here I mean $S$ to be plural, but of course when you do the computation, its for a single surface i.e we can assume the two that work are for different surfaces.